# not taking input in c

Tags: c, clang

```
  char name[20];
  printf("What is your name : ");
  scanf("%s",name);
  char user_grade;
  printf("\nEnter your grade");
  scanf("%c", user_grade);
  switch(user_grade){
    case 'A':
    printf("%s you have passed the exams with great grade !",name);
    break;
    case 'B':
      printf("%s you have passed the exams with good grades!",name);
    break;
    case 'C':
    printf("%s you have passed the exams with nice grades!",name);
    break;
    case 'F':
    printf("%s sorry you have failed the exam..");
    break;
    default:
    printf("sorry your grade are invalid. retry again by typing valid grades");
    break;
  }
```

So the code has to ask the user their name and grade and check if they have passed the exams or not
but the code didn't take the grade input and outputs the result

Comment: @RetiredNinja added this to the answer

Comment: You have forgotten to add `&`. You can write it as `scanf("%c", &user_grade);` .

Answer (score 0):

Try `scanf(" %c", &user_grade);`

Two changes, put a space before `%c` so it will discard any leading whitespace, and pass the address of a variable with `&` so the function can change the variable.

`scanf` expects a pointer for an argument for each item of input. `name` is a pointer because you declared it as an array (although you're probably getting a compiler warning there).

Answer (score 0):

Mainly the issue is that you passed `user_grade` in `scanf("%c", user_grade);` by value. You need to pass it by reference, using `&`: `scanf("%c", &user_grade);`

`char name[20];`, are you sure the name will be under 20 characters long? What if someone entered a name longer than 20 characters?:
`scanf("%s",name);` will just write it to the array irrespective of the size of the array, and your program will crash. So, use `fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);`. But there is an issue here, `fgets()` also returns the newline character `0x0A`/`\n`, so you need to remove it using `name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';`.

A `fflush(stdin);` after `fgets()` might be necessary in some situations here.

Next, you need to pass the variable `user_grade` by reference to `scanf()`, since it needs to memory address of `user_grade` to write to it. Use `scanf(" %c", &user_grade);`.

Here: CREDIT GOES TO @littleadv: to discard leading whitespace use: `scanf(" %c", &user_grade);`

For all of the `printf()` calls inside the switch, its best to add a `\n` to the end of each string to print on screen.

So, your final code would be:

```
char name[20] = {}; // initialize to be safe
printf("What is your name : ");
if (fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin) == NULL) {
    // check for errors
    puts("ERROR reading input!");
    exit(1);
}
name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0'; // needs <string.h>

char user_grade = '0'; // initialized to 0, maybe not needed; I would be on the safe side
printf("\nEnter your grade: ");
scanf(" %c", &user_grade); // pass by reference using `&`

switch (user_grade) {
    case 'A':
        printf("%s you have passed the exams with great grade !\n", name);
        break;
    case 'B':
        printf("%s you have passed the exams with good grades!\n", name);
        break;
    case 'C':
        printf("%s you have passed the exams with nice grades!\n", name);
        break;
    case 'F':
        printf("%s sorry you have failed the exam..\n", name);
        break;
    default:
        printf("sorry your grade are invalid. retry again by typing valid grades\n");
        break;
}
```

Also, you could use `switch (tolower(user_grade)) {` (`tolower()` from `<ctype.h>`) to allow user to enter lowercase grades like `a` and still be accepted.

### Edit:

[@DavidC.Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) suggested that I use `fgets` instead of `scanf` to avoid `\n` being left over and causing problems in loops, so here we can use this instead of `scanf(" %c", &user_grade);`:

```
char user_grade[1024] = {};
fgets(user_grade, 1024, stdin);
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(user_grade); i++) {
    if (user_grade[i] != ' ' && user_grade[i] != '\t') {
        // do the switch here
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For `user_grade`, it's best to read input into a buffer with `fgets()` and then dereference pointer to get first character. E.g., `char buf[1024]; printf(..); fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin); user_grade = *buf;` That way if the code is run in a loop later (which seems likely), the `'\n'` left in `stdin` by `scanf(" %c", &user_grade);` doesn't break the next call to `fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin we can use `fflush(stdin)` at the end instead too, right? I guess `fflush()` causes problems with pipes like `echo -en "xyz\nxyz\nxyz" | ./program`, where the things are removed from the stdin buffer when `fflush()` is called, and unexpected things happen

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, also what if the user enters spaces? We would need to loop through the characters read, and skip all the spaces

Comment: If the user enters spaces, then the easy way to protect against that is to call `char *p = strcspn (buf, " \t"); if (!p) { fputs ("error: whitespace only entered.\n", stderr); return 1; }` And in that case it would then be `user_grade = *p;`.

Comment: Or, simply parse with `sscanf()` as you would use `scanf()`, e.g. `if (sscanf (buf, " %c", &user_score) == 1) { /* valid char obtained */ }`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Nothing wrong with a loop that runs "until a non-space character is encountered" right? I think that's enough. Unnecessary call to `sscanf()` which also needs to parse the format-string

Comment: Reading with `fgets()` and parsing with `sscanf()` is the preferred way. You are correct that looping discarding whitespace is also fine (that's what `strcspn()` described above automates)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Alright :)